# How to mass change theme for all Multisite network sites?

Tags: multisite, themes, bulk

I want to start a new theme for my Multsite install instead of simply modifying the current theme. The problem is I have a lot of sites running on Multsite so it would be a little painful to change all my sites to the new theme one by one.

Is there a way to change the theme of sites by more then one at a time? In sites in network admin I can see a bulk actions option but when I select my sites and click apply, it does nothing (should it!?)

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful? Do you still miss something?

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't recommend to use `update_option` for this task. Why? Because themes/plugins may use `switch_theme` action and it won't get run in such case. And this action is pretty important - it will allow you to save your widgets for example...

Another problem with Fuxias answer is that she uses `template_directory` hook. But there is no point to run it every time. If you set the theme, it is set, so you have to do it only once.

Here's the code that will loop through all subsites and set the theme to given one. Put it on your site, run once and then delete it (or comment it):

```
function switch_all_multisite_themes() {
    foreach ( get_sites() as $site ) {
        switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );

        switch_theme( 'twentyeleven' );

        restore_current_blog();
    }
}
switch_all_multisite_themes();  // run this function only once
```

Comment: Since the get_sites can just run to 100 by default: http://hookr.io/functions/get_sites/; maybe is required a modification with big networks 

( get_sites(array('fields' => 'ids', 'number' => NumberOfSitesOfTheNetwork))

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can add this snippet to your MU network homepage site's `functions.php` and refresh the frontend one time, then delete the snippet after confirming your other sites have successfully changed themes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [MU plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and filter `'template_directory'`.

Sample code to force TwentyEleven on all sites:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
// Plugin Name: Force Styleswitch
// 08.06.2012
add_filter( 'template_directory', 't5_switch_theme', 10, 3 );

function t5_switch_theme( $template_dir, $template, $theme_root )
{
    $forced_theme = 'twentyeleven';

    if ( $template !== $forced_theme )
        update_option( 'stylesheet', $forced_theme );

    return "$theme_root/$forced_theme";
}
```

You could also iterate over all blogs – use `get_blog_count()` and `switch_to_blog()` – and run the update just once.

The **Network enable** action in `wp-admin/network/themes.php` just makes a theme available on a site, it doesn’t set it as active theme.

Comment: Why don't you use `switch_theme` function and you're doing it the hard way with `update_option`?