# Acivate all themes multisite wide automatically

Tags: theme-development, multisite, themes

I have a multi-site running locally. And it annoys me that I have to activate themes individually until I can use them on the sites.

I am super admin, what is the reason WordPress handles plugins differently here? I see all plugin on all sites automatically and can activate them. I like to have themes behave in the same way. Can I do this somehow. Some little tricky powerful function that automatically activates all (new) themes dropped into `/wp-content/themes` network wide automatically?

Again in case this words are not clear enough:

I want to have all themes inside my themes directory available/enabled for switching on all sites without me doing anything. Exactly like plugins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Multisite themes on mass](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54543/changing-multisite-themes-on-mass)